# Command-T in emacs

Tags: plugins, emacs

Is there something similar to the CommandT plugin in vim for emacs? I know some plugins that do directory-based completion, but is there one that does matching on the full paths?

An example:

```
├── bar
│   └── hello
├── baz
│   └── test
│       └── hello
└── foo
    ├── hello
    └── lost

baz
baz/test
baz/test/hello
bar
bar/hello
foo
foo/hello
foo/lost
```

Now when I type 'h', I'd like the paths

```
baz/test/hello
bar/hello
foo/hello
```

to match. For 't', there should be

```
baz/test/hello
foo/lost
```

Comment: Perhaps you could describe the "CommandT plugin in vim" so that Emacs users have some hope of answering your question?

Comment: There would be a nice screencast, but looks like the web isn't totally rid of quicktime yet. https://wincent.com/products/command-t

Comment: I asked pretty much the same question  here, and got some other answers that might prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631325/command-t-for-emacs.

Comment: I considered implementing something like that myself, IIRC it ended up as a helm matcher somewhere. The biggest problem is speed, elisp simply isn't fast enough, and stallman doesn't like linking C into emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) does this AFAIK, and also [anything.el](http://metasandwich.com/2010/07/30/what-can-i-get-for-10-dolla-anything-el/).

Also, [this emacswiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocateFilesAnywhere) has a list packages which do something similar.

Edit: According to Drew's comment Ido does not match the whole path. Anything on the other hand does, as it can be seen on the screenshot behind the link.

Comment: AFAIK, Ido does *not* match absolute file names. Like ordinary Emacs file-name completion, you can of course match a prefix to change directories (navigate the directory hierarchy), but AFAIK Ido adds nothing to the mix for matching different parts of a file-name "path" (directory part).

Comment: Thanks, I've added your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

[***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) does matching on full paths (i.e., any and all parts of an absolute file name).  See [*Icicles File-Name Input*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input).

By default, in **Icicle** mode <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> is bound to `icicle-file`:

- without a prefix arg -- uses the usual Emacs relative file-name completion
- with a prefix arg (e.g. <kbd>C-u C-x C-f</kbd>) -- does absolute file-name completion

Command `icicle-find-file-absolute` is the same as <kbd>C-u C-x C-f</kbd>. You can bind it if you don't want to use the key sequence <kbd>C-u C-x C-f</kbd> each time.

During completion of either type (relative/absolute file names), you can use any of the **Icicles** completion features, such as:

- [progressive completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion) (match name parts in any order)
- [candidate help](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Help_on_Candidates)
- [candidate cycling](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Cycling_Completions)
- [candidate sorting](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Sorting_Candidates)
- [fuzzy completion](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion) (the Vim screencast you cite uses the equivalent of **Icicles** "scatter" matching and Ido "flex" matching)

And file-name completion commands such as these are [multi-commands](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands), which means you can act on multiple files with the same command.  See also command `icicle-locate`, which does absolute file-name matching and lets you find and act on files anywhere on your file system, without knowing their locations.